# AWS Elastic Load Balancer holding up port

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, express, networking, elastic-load-balancer

I have some EC2 instances running an express application listening on port 3000. I then have an elastic load balancer forwarding request from it's port 80 to these EC2 instances. Every time I bring down one of the express servers running on an EC2 instance and try to bring it back up I get the address in use error for port 3000. I can not find any actual process using this port (lsof, netstat, etc) is ELB still connected on port 3000 ? If so what is the workflow to restart applications behind ELB ?

Comment: How are you bringing the server/process down?

Comment: This doesn't sound related to the ELB. It sounds like the process isn't actually shutting down properly on the server when you go to stop it. Add more info about how you are shutting down the service.

Comment: I am just using ctrl+c making some changes then trying to bring server back up

Comment: Server is an express server

Comment: This is probably not the issue, I have been doing this just fine until I started using ELB

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ["Connection Draining"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-conn-drain.html) and either disable it or reduce the time.

It sounds like the process isn't exiting until all connections have closed.

Comment: Okay will take a look, can I manually destroy all connections when the server exits ?